# Is Valonqar prophecy unfulfilled?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S8E5, we see that

> Cersei dies along with Jaime in a rubble cave in,

and most definitely not by

> one of her brothers killing her

as the Valonqar prophecy states. The prophecy says:

> **When your tears have drowned you, the Valonqar shall wrap his hands about your pale white throat and choke life from you**

This obviously hasn't been fulfilled. Is this prophecy now just moot? Just Why?

Comment: Didn't they skip that line in the shows?

Comment: All of the secret Lannister theories missed the obvious answer: Cersei's secret brother was the brick ceiling of the castle basement. Makes perfect sense in hindsight.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The prophecy is unfulfilled but the valonqar was never a part of the prophecy in the show. In the show Cersei is only meant to be cast down by someone younger and more beautiful... depending on how you interpret the show's events will lead you to either think it was fulfilled or wasn't.

> MAGGY: Three questions you get. You won’t like the answers.
>
> CERSEI: I’ve been promised to the prince. When will we marry?
>
> MAGGY: You’ll never wed the prince. You’ll wed the king.
>
> CERSEI: But I will be queen?
>
> MAGGY: Oh yes, you’ll be queen. For a time. In comes another. Younger, more beautiful, to cast you down and take all you hold dear.
>
> CERSEI: Will the king and I have children?
>
> MAGGY: No. The king will have 20 children, and you will have 3.
>
> CERSEI: That doesn’t make sense.
>
> MAGGY: Gold will be their crowns. Gold their shrouds.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Episode 5, "The Wars to Come"</sub>

In the books Maggy goes further to talk about the valonqar but as you can see above this is skipped in the show.

> The old woman was not done with her, however. "Gold shall be their crowns and gold their shrouds," she said. "And when your tears have drowned you, the valonqar shall wrap his hands about your pale white throat and choke the life from you."
>
> <sub>*A Feast for Crows*, Cersei VIII</sub>

Comment: Younger and more beautiful - Jon?

Comment: @okutane, presumably Danaerys, but depends on your preferences I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

We don't really know her exact status as of the end of the episode. And while the literal interpretation of the prophesy seems unlikely, I would argue that if she dies of suffocation with her brother's arms wrapped around her then metaphorically the prophesy does come true.

And whether the prophesy comes true or not doesn't really matter because the main purpose of it seems to be giving Cersei a reason to always and forever despise Tyrion.

Comment: Maybe they're buried in rubble and Jamie has to mercifully strangle her to death to end her suffering?

Comment: @FoxDeploy Let's... uh... lets skip that deleted scene.

Comment: @FoxDeploy The prophecy stated "his hands", of which Jamie has one, not two.